# How to modify documentation built with sphinx via a script in readthedocs build

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am trying to run a script to modify the documentation built by sphinx hosted by Read the Docs (because some links are not properly handled). The script works when I try to build it locally, but either fails on the Read the Docs build or the changes do not get propagated to the web site.

**The script I'm trying to run is super simple, it replaces some html links that are not properly converted by sphinx-markdown-tables:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# fix_table_links.sh
FILE="_build/html/api_reference.html"
if [[ "$1" != "" ]]; then
  FILE="$1"
fi
sed -E 's/a href="(.*)\.md"/a href="\1\.html"/g' -i ${FILE}
```

**My readthedocs.yml looks like this:**

```
# Required
version: 2

# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
  configuration: docs/conf.py

# Optionally build your docs in additional formats such as PDF and ePub
formats: all

# Optionally set the version of Python and requirements required to build your docs
python:
  install:
    - requirements: docs/requirements.readthedocs.txt

build:
  os: ubuntu-20.04
  tools:
    python: "3.8"
  jobs:
    post_build:
      - echo "Running post-build commands."
      - bash docs/fix_table_links.sh _readthedocs/html/api_reference.html
```

**There are two cases:**

**Case 1)** Using the `readthedocs.yml` as above, the build fails because `_readthedocs/html/api_reference.html` does not exist, despite this directory being the place the documentation claims will get uploaded from [here](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#build-commands). An example failure of this run is [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/openspiel/builds/17868852/).

**Case 2)** If I change the final of `readthedocs.yml` to `bash docs/fix_table_links.sh docs/_build/html/api_reference.html`, then the build passes (example [here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/openspiel/builds/17864031/)). But the links are not updated on the Read the Docs site: they still point to markdown pages rather than their corresponding HTML pages, so it must not be the version that gets uploaded to the Read the Docs web site.

Wading through documentation, I can't figure out how do this. Has anybody done this before or have a better grasp on how Read the Docs builds work? Thanks!

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but I have found a bypass solution: do the rewriting of the markdown files *before* the build to change all the links in the markdown file instead of after the build.

It's now working, commit details here: https://github.com/deepmind/open_spiel/commit/0e0ae2f1827f24dafe82372d1bf4ea1729cb9566. Shiny new API reference in Read the Docs now up here: https://openspiel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html. So I'm happy, but it'd still be great to know why the other way was not working.

Comment: Case 1) is not working as you expects because "_readthedocs/html" directory is only used when "build.commands" is used. We have an issue opened to make it the default directory for all the builders. See https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/9554

Comment: Case 2) is not working as you expects because there is a bug on Read the Docs (see https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/9172)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to rewrite the script as a Python function, then you can do this super easily by connecting it as an event handler for the [`build-finished` event](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#event-build-finished).

I've done something similar [in one of my own repos](https://github.com/TDKorn/insta-tweet/blob/master/docs/source/conf.py#L440), except I post-process a `.rst` file. It's not actually used on RTD, but I can see it works in the build logs. So it should work to post-process your HTML files as well, since the `build-finished` event would occur after they've been generated.

First, define the script as a function in your `conf.py`. It needs to have `app` and `exception` as parameters.

```
def replace_html_links(app, exception):
    with open(FILE, 'r') as f:
        html = f.read()
    # stuff to edit and save the html
```

Then either define or add to your `setup` function:

```
def setup(app):
    app.connect('build-finished', replace_html_links)
```

And that's it!